# How to scroll through pages in previewed pdf's on Dolphin file manager?

Tags: kde, pdf, dolphin, previews

Im using Dolphin file manager on Ubuntu 18.04LTS, my desktop environment is KDE Plasma.

Dolphin already previews all my files in the information panel (enabled with the key F11) but for pdf's it only shows the first page of the pdf and i can't scroll through the pages like i do in windows 10.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Thats no "real" preview of the file, but just a thumbnail created for it.
So scrolling is not possible.

Unfortunately there seems to be no real KDE/Plasma/Dolphin-alternative to gnomes sushi or gloobus, both of which work with Nautilus. In Plasma 4 there used to be klook, but it never got ported to plasma 5 afaik.